# AttributeError: 'mail.template' object has no attribute 'generate_email'

Tags: python, email, browser, odoo, email-templates

I am using `Odoo` browser and want to generate email from template and send. I don't want to use the `send_mail()` method directly. Here is my code.

```
data = records
template_object = env['mail.template']
template_id = template_object.search([('name', '=', 'Custom_Email_Template')]).id
for record in data:
    template = template_object.browse(template_id)
    email_body = template.generate_email(record.id)
    email_values = {
    'subject': "",
    'body_html': email_body,
    'email_to': 'some@example.com'   }

env['mail.mail'].create(email_values).send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the [fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py#L184) parameter

***Example***

```py
values = template.generate_email(record.id, ['body_html'])
```

**Edit:**
You can try the following in a demo database:

```py
template = env.ref('sale.mail_template_sale_confirmation')
record = env.ref('sale.sale_order_7')
values = template.generate_email(record.id, ['body_html'])

body_html = values['body_html']
```

Comment: Got the same error "AttributeError: 'mail.template' object has no attribute 'generate_email'"

Comment: Try it with the sale confirmation template, check my edit